# How to parse URL from anchor tag

Tags: c#, html, regex

I want to retrieve URL in `<a>` tag in `HTML` document. Here's the tag:

```
<a href="index.php?option=com_remository&amp;Itemid=43&amp;func=fileinfo&amp;id=49"><img src="http://dziekanat.wzim.sggw.pl/components/com_remository/images/file_icons/New.gif" width="16" height="16" border="0" align="middle" alt="file_icons/New.gif"/><b>&nbsp;Plan STAC lato 2014_15</b></a>
```

After parse I should get

`index.php?option=com_remository&amp;Itemid=43&amp;func=fileinfo&amp;id=49`

What regex pattern should I use?

I'd like to do this with regex since HTML document itself is very old and lacks of any IDs to reference. Therefore I cannot do it with any more sophisticated tool (like [Html Agility Pack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)).

The whole document can be found here: http://dziekanat.wzim.sggw.pl/index.php?option=com_remository&Itemid=43&func=select&id=2

Comment: How are you locating this particular `<a>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Therefore I cannot do it with any more sophisticated tool (like [Html Agility Pack](http://Therefore%20I%20cannot%20do%20it%20with%20any%20more%20sophisticated%20tool%20(like%20Html%20Agility%20Pack).)).

Why not? This works for me

```
var html = new Webclient().DownloadString("http://dziekanat.wzim.sggw.pl/index.php?option=com_remository&Itemid=43&func=select&id=2");
var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);


var links = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("a")
            .Select(a => a.Attributes["href"].Value)
            .ToList();
```

This Xpath returns your link

```
var link = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[@class='sectiontableentry1']//a")
            .Attributes["href"].Value;
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score -1):

Here you go:

```
string Pattern = @"<a[^>]*?href\s*=\s*[""']?([^'"" >]+?)[ '""][^>]*?>";
```